# Scrapy-splash can't scrape any element

Tags: javascript, scrapy, splash-screen

I try to scrape this [site](https://bsr.sudrf.ru/bigs/portal.html#%7B%22groups%22:%5B%22%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%22%5D,%22sorts%22:%5B%7B%22field%22:%22score%22,%22order%22:%22desc%22%7D%5D,%22type%22:%22MULTIQUERY%22,%22multiqueryRequest%22:%7B%22queryRequests%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22Q%22,%22request%22:%22%7B%5C%22mode%5C%22:%5C%22EXTENDED%5C%22,%5C%22typeRequests%5C%22:%5B%7B%5C%22fieldRequests%5C%22:%5B%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D,%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%20%20%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%201%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D,%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%20%20%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%202%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D,%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%20%20%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%203%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D%5D,%5C%22mode%5C%22:%5C%22AND%5C%22,%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%5C%22,%5C%22typesMode%5C%22:%5C%22AND%5C%22%7D%5D%7D%22,%22operator%22:%22AND%22,%22queryRequestRole%22:%22CATEGORIES%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22SQ%22,%22queryId%22:%229627aab7-0ec7-4677-a3df-500782fa8739%22,%22operator%22:%22AND%22%7D%5D%7D,%22simpleSearchFieldsBundle%22:null,%22noOrpho%22:false%7D)

Command *fetch('site')* returns me *crawled(200)*.

But when I try to get any of css selectors, it returns an empty list.

I realised that this page is generated with JavaScript ant tried to use Splash.

*fetch('http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=**[site](https://bsr.sudrf.ru/bigs/portal.html#%7B%22groups%22:%5B%22%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%22%5D,%22sorts%22:%5B%7B%22field%22:%22score%22,%22order%22:%22desc%22%7D%5D,%22type%22:%22MULTIQUERY%22,%22multiqueryRequest%22:%7B%22queryRequests%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22Q%22,%22request%22:%22%7B%5C%22mode%5C%22:%5C%22EXTENDED%5C%22,%5C%22typeRequests%5C%22:%5B%7B%5C%22fieldRequests%5C%22:%5B%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D,%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%20%20%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%201%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D,%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%20%20%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%202%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D,%7B%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22u_case_user_article%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22EX%5C%22,%5C%22query%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%20247%20%20%20%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%203%5C%22,%5C%22sQuery%5C%22:null%7D%5D,%5C%22mode%5C%22:%5C%22AND%5C%22,%5C%22name%5C%22:%5C%22%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%5C%22,%5C%22typesMode%5C%22:%5C%22AND%5C%22%7D%5D%7D%22,%22operator%22:%22AND%22,%22queryRequestRole%22:%22CATEGORIES%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22SQ%22,%22queryId%22:%229627aab7-0ec7-4677-a3df-500782fa8739%22,%22operator%22:%22AND%22%7D%5D%7D,%22simpleSearchFieldsBundle%22:null,%22noOrpho%22:false%7D)**')* also returns 200, but *response.css* returns nothing.

Why splash doesn't work hier? What can help me?

Will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The site returns 403 access denied even when accessed from a normal web browser. Therefore splash would return the same content as a normal browser and `response.css` yields nothing.

[image]